# grub cant see win7 bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

i have installed a Win7 and Ubuntu 16 afterwards and wanted to dualboot via GRUB. Here is the output from

```
sudo  blkid 

/dev/sda1: UUID="4bf25393-75d2-4ac4-8dd8-655171beb021" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="c96b3c5a-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Dateien" UUID="06C2F067C2F05BFD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="00127852-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Backup" UUID="3CF00D72F00D3424" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="00127852-02"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Data" UUID="6E22898B2289594B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="49425204-01"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Windows" UUID="7AFC4E2DFC4DE44B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d8e3d0d0-01"
```

GRUB already recognizes a boot loader for Win7 on sdb1 but I would prefer to have the boot loader on the same disk as my Win7, since I'd like to erase the other hard drives completely. So I copied all necessary files to sdd1 and added into my

```
/boot/grub/menu.lst

title           Microsoft 7test
rootnoverify    (hd3,0)
savedefault
chainloader     +1
```

but Grub still doesn't recognizes the win boot loader on sdd1, but the one on sdb1 (which boots, but meh).

I already have read several posts, but i couldn't get anything to work.

thanks^^

Comment: Grub2 does not use menu.lst, that is from grub legacy back in 2009. Have you run `sudo update-grub` ? But os-prober has to see Windows boot files bootmgr & /Boot/BCD to know a partition is bootable. Windows uses boot flag.

Comment: `/dev/sdb1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain` and
`/dev/sdd1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows1:chain` are the results of os-prober. i already used update-grub, but only the sdb got added.

Comment: It says it found it. Do you have more than one install, or mulitiple grubs and a different one is booting. Or so many menu items that last item is below the box of menu items and you have to scroll down?  If not those issues post link above: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I only have 5 entries in my menu (ubuntu, 3 ubuntu recoveries/mem-tests  and win7 on sdb). My grub recognized the sdd once, when i first installed ubuntu, then I used `apt install grub` cause I thought I'ld need it and now it disappeared. I'll post a link as soon as I am at home :)

Comment: If you did an apt install grub, that would have been the grub legacy version and its search for Windows 7 was weak. To  get grub2 and its much better os-prober it is package grub-pc if BIOS or grub-efi-amd64 if 64 bit UEFI. Best to totally uninstall all versions of grub & reinstall grub2 completely. You can do it manually or use Boot-Repair and its advanced options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

purge old and reinstall new to sda - BIOS

```
sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Or in Boot-Repair's advanced options check reinstall grub main options and uninstall old version in grub options.

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: well the reinstall worked (as far as i can judge, i can boot from sdd now, but i did not remove the sdb bootloader yet) , I never thought, that you can simply copy the bootfiles, but hey... :) @oldfred , thanks very much, if I knew  your adress, I'ld send you flowers and a box of cholcolate^^ thanks very much . I've nearly lost my faith in PCs at this problem^^